# How to select value get in php form from mysql for update the data

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the value of already selected option from the database mysql through php. title and post value i got the right from the database on the current $id but the value of selected box not showing what is already selected please help me to get rid of this error

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "alurdu_db"; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows >0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
  echo '<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
  echo '<div class="form-group">';
  echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_title" value="' . $row["title"] . '">';
  echo '<select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat">';
  echo '<option value="National" if($row["news_cat"] == "National") echo "selected";>National</option>';
  echo '<option value="International" if($row["news_cat"] == "International") echo "selected";>International</option>';
  echo '</select>';
  echo '</form>'
}

} else {
echo "Wrong Page";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: <option value="National" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == 'National')? "selected" : "" ?>>National</option>

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check `database stored` value is `equal to current option value`. if it is equal you need to add `selected property` .

```
<option value="National" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == 'National')? "selected" : "" ?>>National</option>
```

**Update 1** : problem is your single quotes and double quotes escaping. just use like this instead of echoing the form .

```
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      ?>

        <form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-2 text-center">News Title
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_title" value="<?=$row["title"]?>">
           </div> 
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">Category
               <select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat" >
                   <option value="National" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "National")? "selected" : "" ?> >National</option> 
                   <option value="International" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "International")? "selected" : "" ?> > International</option> 
               </select> 
             </div>  
              <div class="col-md-12">  
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="detail" ><?= $row["post"] ?></textarea>
              </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-align" style="background-color:#3c8dbc;color:white">Update</button>
                </div>
               </div>

         </form>

       <?php

        }
```

**Update 2 :**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "alurdu_db";
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {    
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id='$id'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
         if ($result->num_rows >0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      ?>

        <form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-2 text-center">News Title
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_title" value="<?=$row["title"]?>">
           </div> 
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">Category
               <select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat" >
                   <option value="National" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "National")? "selected" : "" ?> >National</option> 
                   <option value="International" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "International")? "selected" : "" ?> > International</option> 
               </select> 
             </div>  
              <div class="col-md-12">  
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="detail" ><?= $row["post"] ?></textarea>
              </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-align" style="background-color:#3c8dbc;color:white">Update</button>
                </div>
               </div>

         </form>

       <?php

        }

     } else {
        echo "Wrong Page";
    }

    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'National' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\admin\pages\manage-news\ops.php on line 25 this error giving JYoThl sir

Comment: because your echoing the form so be careful on single quotes double quotes escape @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Comment: try this one <option value="National" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "National")? "selected" : "" ?>>National</option>

Comment: inside the echo just use double quotes like above comment @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Comment: <select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat" selected="' . $row["news_cat"] . '"></div>
               <option value="National" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "National")? "selected" : "" ?> >National</option>
               <option value="International" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "International")? "selected" : "" ?> > International</option>
           </select>

Comment: i have write this code but it still showing only national but i have selected the id with international :( i don't know where is error comming

Comment: add the empty option in option list first like this  <option value="">select</option> @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Comment: echo $row["news_cat"]; and know that value is correct or not

Comment: if i write code get value of the news_cat it showing correct in options value but why not selected  <select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat" selected="' . $row["news_cat"] . '">
               <option value="" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "National")? "selected" : "" ?> >'.$row["news_cat"].'</option>
           </select>

Comment: check my update one @MuhammadUmarGulzar it will surely solve your issue . i tested too

Comment: remove this unwanted *selected="' . $row["news_cat"] . '"*

Comment: <option value="National" <?php if(" '$row["news_cat"]' == "National"") echo "selected"; ?> >National</option> what is the error in this code?

Comment: inside the single quotes  everything consider as string so if you use php you need to escape it properly .  @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Comment: Respective Sir i use this one but it does not working still :( <select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat">
            <option value="National" echo <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "National")? "selected" : "" ?> >National</option>
            <option value="International" <?= ($row["news_cat"] == "International")? "selected" : "" ?> >International</option>
           </select>

Comment: did you changed the code like above udpate 1 ?  instead of echo '<form .. </form> ':   remove the echo and close the ?> php tag like this and start the pure html and end again start the <php } like this

Comment: when i write in single quotes  it showing me error like this 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'National' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\admin\pages\manage-news\ops.php on line 25

Comment: did you changed the code like above udpate 1 ? instead of echo '<form .. </form> ': remove the echo and close the ?> php tag like this and start the pure html and end again start the <php } like this i not understand this i have save the file in .php and not use the html tag i start from <?php and end with ?> 2 filed working already title and text area but select is only thing which is not working

Comment: just copy past my update 2 and try it . hopefully it will work . @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Comment: 2 filed getting the right data from the data bases only the select field not getting the data

Comment: alot of comments what is 2 update :( am sorry i disturbing u i appreciate for urs kind help

Comment: yes first of you need to know the different between single quotes and double quotes in php and how should be escape it while using each other . @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Comment: but i am saying my code is working for 2 fields in form which are input type text fields the only field not getting the data from mysql is select box i write same as u update the <?php if($row["news_cat"] == 'National') the national in this getting dark blue and giving the error but i wrote in single quote the 'national' the error remove but not showing the correct result

Comment: it should be like this <option value="National" <? if (($row["news_cat"]) == 'National') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> >National</option> you can copy and pasted this line i have used it many times like this it works

Comment: because on that two fields you properly concatenated like this so its working . value="' . $row["title"] . '"

Comment: omg how many comments . anyway glad to help you . don't forgot to mark it with green tick because it's useful for future user reference @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Answer (score 0):

Please replace below code for select box

```
<select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat"></div>
<option value="National" <?php if($row["news_cat"]=="National"){echo "selected";} ?> >National</option>
<option value="International" <?php if($row["news_cat"]=="International"){echo "selected";} ?> >International</option>
```

i hope this works for you

Comment: okay than please share your result array so i can try different way

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'National' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\admin\pages\manage-news\ops.php on line 25 this error showing

Comment: hello @MuhammadUmarGulzar

Please try below code

<?php
$row['news_cat'] = "National";

?>

<select dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" name="news_cat"></div>
    <option value="National" <?php if($row["news_cat"]=="National"){echo "selected";} ?> >National</option>
    <option value="International" <?php if($row["news_cat"]=="International"){echo "selected";} ?> >International</option>
</select>

above code works for me